# I tried to send dicom file using dcmsend getting "Association Request Failed: 0006:0321 Unrecognized PDU type: 53"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dicom

I tried to send dicom file using dcmsend getting

> "Association Request Failed: 0006:0321 Unrecognized PDU type: 53"

Getting response as follow

```
D: $dcmtk: dcmsend v3.6.3+ DEV $
D: 
I: checking input files ...
D: adding DICOM file '/Users/at009/Downloads/Dicom-3.dcm'
D: getting SOP Class UID, SOP Instance UID and Transfer Syntax UID from DICOM file
D: DcmMetaInfo::checkAndReadPreamble() TransferSyntax="Little Endian Explicit"
D: trying to get SOP Class UID, SOP Instance UID and Transfer Syntax UID from meta-header
D: successfully added SOP instance 1.2.840.114191.3.6817226.2247938.26.1.5.1.1558014084 to the transfer list
D: in total, there are 1 SOP instances to be sent, 0 invalid files are ignored
D: multiple associations allowed (option --multi-associations used)
D: preparing presentation context for SOP Class / Transfer Syntax: DigitalMammographyXRayImageStorageForPresentation / Little Endian Explicit
D: added new presentation context with ID 1
D: -----------------------------------------------------------------
D: starting association #1
I: initializing network ...
D: Configured a total of 1 presentation contexts for SCU
I: negotiating network association ...
D: Request Parameters:
D: ====================== BEGIN A-ASSOCIATE-RQ =====================
D: Our Implementation Class UID:      1.2.276.0.7230010.3.0.3.6.3
D: Our Implementation Version Name:   OFFIS_DCMTK_363
D: Their Implementation Class UID:    
D: Their Implementation Version Name: 
D: Application Context Name:    1.2.840.10008.3.1.1.1
D: Calling Application Name:    Test
D: Called Application Name:     IMPORTADAPTER
D: Responding Application Name: IMPORTADAPTER
D: Our Max PDU Receive Size:    16384
D: Their Max PDU Receive Size:  0
D: Presentation Contexts:
D:   Context ID:        1 (Proposed)
D:     Abstract Syntax: =DigitalMammographyXRayImageStorageForPresentation
D:     Proposed SCP/SCU Role: Default
D:     Proposed Transfer Syntax(es):
D:       =LittleEndianExplicit
D:       =BigEndianExplicit
D:       =LittleEndianImplicit
D: Requested Extended Negotiation: none
D: Accepted Extended Negotiation:  none
D: Requested User Identity Negotiation: none
D: User Identity Negotiation Response:  none
D: ======================= END A-ASSOCIATE-RQ ======================
I: Requesting Association
D: setting network send timeout to 60 seconds
D: setting network receive timeout to 60 seconds
D: Constructing Associate RQ PDU
D: Association Request Failed: 0006:0321 Unrecognized PDU type: 53
F: cannot negotiate network association: Unrecognized PDU type: 53
D: Cleaning up internal association and network structures
11:06:49 Send job terminated with result: 61
```

Comment: What GCP Product are you using? It is not clear what is your exact set up so it is hard for anyone in the community to help. I suggest to add more details to you question as per this [help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have refereed URL: "https://cloud.google.com/healthcare/docs/how-tos/dicom-connect-pacs".  Created dicomstore and deployed dicom-adapter using Google Kubernetes Engine. Created VM instance in gcp. Using ssh of VM , able to send DCM files using DCMSEND command but when i tried to send dicom image using external ip of VM it gives me above error.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at "Unrecognized PDU type" in log, this looks closely related to *wrong* network; a very wrong data on network.

Are you sure you are sending to correct destination node? Is the node you are sending to, capable of receiving DICOM?

Looking at your "google-..." tag, the listener might be expecting HTTP(S) and you are pushing DICOM.

Note that "data format/protocol" and "network protocol" are two different things. Your "google-..." stuff might be supporting DICOM as data format but network protocol might be different; say HTTP.

There are ways to communicate DICOM data on web; but that is entirely different topic.